# Store the value from pandas dataframe without index or header

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to get the values from a CSV file using python and pandas. To avoid index and headers i am using .values with iloc but as an output my value is stored in [] brackets. I dont want them i just need the value. I dont want to print it but want to use it for other operations.

My code is :

```
import pandas as pd
ctr_x = []
ctr_y = []
tl_list = []
br_list = []
object_list = []
img = None

obj = 'red_hat'
df = pd.read_csv('ring_1_05_sam.csv')
ctr_x = df.iloc[10:12, 0:1].values #to avoid headers and index
ctr_y = df.iloc[10:12, 1:2].values #to avoid headers and index

ctr_x =[]
ctr_y =[]
```

If i print the result of ctr_x and ctr_y to check if correct values are recorded
The output i get is :

```
[[1536.25]
[1536.5 ]]
[[895.25]
[896.  ]]
```

So i short i am getting the correct values but i don't want the brackets. Can anyone please suggest any other alternatives to my method. Note : I dont want to print the values but store it(without index and headers) for further operations

Comment: What further operations are you doing that require the data to stored in this way? I suspect what you are doing is unnecessary.

Comment: the ctr_x and ctr_y contain center coordinates of a circle. i am storing this data from the CSV file(which has 3000 rows and 2 columns) and then later will operate +- 25 from each value to generate top left and bottom right coordinates of bounding boxes to generate a xml file. so yeah i need just singular values for ctr_x and ctr_y to achieve my goal and not the index and header

Comment: I am not sure how the xml file would treat [] boxes. So i want to get rid of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use column slice, pandas returns a Dataframe. Try

```
type(df.iloc[10:12, 0:1])
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

This in turn will return a 2-D array when you use

```
df.iloc[10:12, 0:1].values
```

If you want a 1 dimensional array, you can use integer indexing which will return a Series,

```
type(df.iloc[10:12, 0])
pandas.core.series.Series
```

And a one dimensional array,

```
df.iloc[10:12, 0].values
```

So use

```
ctr_x = df.iloc[10:12, 0].values
ctr_y = df.iloc[10:12, 1].values
```

Comment: I think i have not used it correctly but it gives me an output of  " <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>" . This is where i am supposed to use it right? " ctr_x = type(df.iloc[10:12, 0:1])"

Comment: ok. I still havent figured out how to use it. Would be very helpful and nice if you could show  how to use this format in my code if you have time

Comment: thanks for the edit, but what i wanted was an output of just the values without the brackets. With this i still get brackets in output something like [1537.   1537.   1536.25 1536.5 ].So i think they are also stored with the brackets. Is there any way to get rid of the brackets?

Comment: @ Vaishali. I just solved it.using ctr_x = df.iloc[10:12, 0].values.tolist() solves the issue completely. The data is stored and when using it later, the brackets are also eliminated. Thanks for your answer.